# How to show $f^{-1}(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth map. I'm wondering about smoothness of the set $f^{-1}(0)$ under the following conditions:

(1) For all $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $f^{-1}(0) \cap (\{x\} \times \mathbb{R}^n)$ is smooth of dimension $r$ (if non-empty). The dimension stays the same for all $x$.

(2) For all $(x, y) \in f^{-1}(0)$ the restriction of the projection $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ to the kernel of $df_{(x,y)}$ is surjective. In other words, for all $u \in \mathbb{R}^m$ there exists $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $df_{(x,y)}(u, v) = 0$.

Why is $f^{-1}(0)$ a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$? (Maybe it isn't, but I've seen that claim somewhere, that's why I'm asking.)

I'm trying to apply the transversality theorem, but it's not obvious how since $df_{(x,y)}$ may not be surjective. Intuitively, by (1), non-smoothness can only arise in the transverse directions $\mathbb{R}^m \times \{y\}$ but because $\ker df_{(x,y)} \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is surjective that cannot happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems wrong to me; perhaps I'm overlooking something, so please double-check this carefully.

Take $m=n=1$ and $r=0$. Let $f\colon\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be given by $$f(x,y)=x^2-y^2.$$ $f^{-1}(0)$ is the set $|y|=|x|$, and the fibers when you project to the $x$-axis are $0$-dimensional (disconnected other than the origin). The kernel of $df_{(x,y)}$ jumps dimension at the origin, but your surjectivity criterion then holds even more easily.

Comment: I double-checked carefully and I think you're correct.